# Elements of $\sigma(T)$ if $T^m = T^n$ for $m>n$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Suppose we have a complex Hilbert space $H$ and a $T \in B(H)$ such that $T^m = T^n$ for some integers $m > n \geq 1$. If $\lambda \in \sigma(T)$, then $\lambda = 0$ or $\lambda^{m-n} = 1$.

I think the way to prove this is by using $\sigma(T^{m-n}) = \sigma(T)^{m-n}$. Because if $\lambda \in \sigma(T)$, then $\lambda^{m-n} \in \sigma(T^{m-n})$, so $T^{m-n} - \lambda^{m-n}I$ is not invertible. Therefore $T^n(T^{m-n} - \lambda^{m-n}I) = T^m - \lambda^{m-n}I$ is not invertible, and using $T^m = T^n$ we see that $T^n(1-\lambda^{m-n})$ is not invertible. This means that either $T^n$ is not invertible or $\lambda^{m-n} = 1$. If $T^n$ is not invertible, then $T$ is not invertible, so $0 \in \sigma(T)$. However, we can't conclude that $\lambda = 0$.

Is this the right way or is there a better method?

Answer (score 2):

by the Spectral Mapping Theorem, $\{0\} = \sigma(T^m - T^n) = \{\lambda^m - \lambda^n : \lambda \in \sigma(T)\}$.  If $\lambda^m - \lambda^n = 0$, then either $\lambda = 0$ or $\lambda^{m-n} = 1$.